# Triggering a hudson job by e-mail

Tags: hudson

For the life of me i cannot get this to work. I've spent almost 4 hours on this and it just does not work. I would like to start hudson job when an e-mail is sent to a specific user. I looked and followed the info mentionned here: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Building+a+software+project
 but still cannot get it to work.

Here is a summary of what i've done so far:

Modified /etc/aliases such that any email going to usr1 trigger the build as in

usr1: "|wget http://hudson-server/hudson/job/myjob/build"

I reconstructed the aliases db after making the above changes and sent out an e-mail to usr1 but nothing happened.

Our emails run on an exchange server. My hudson server sits on a linux box. I tried to use sendmail to do my testing and cannot get it to work. All of the above changes are done on linux. So i'm not sure if the issue here is with sendmail/exchange server or is something i'm missing.

Has anyone got this to work?

I appreciate your help here guys.

Britney

Comment: Might try asking this on serverfault.  They might have better ideas.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check:

1. Make sure that running `wget http://hudson-server/hudson/job/myjob/build` from the command line successfully starts a build.  You may have problems if you have security on the server (or the job).
2. Make sure your exchange server is forwarding the mail for the email address in question to the mail server running on your linux box.  If the mail isn't being received there, the `wget` command in aliases won't ever get executed.

Comment: Thanks a bunch highlycaffeinated. Yes executing wget from the cmd line starts the job successfully. As of now Hudson is not secure. I'm not sure about the exchange server mail forwarding. All i can say for now, is that, if i use sendmail and send an e-mail to myself from a linux box, then i do get it in outlook. I'm not sure how to check if the forwarding occurs in the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending the email to usr1? Are you sending it from the same Linux box where the /etc/aliases is located?

To test your setup, on your Linux machine, send your email like this:

```
mail -s "test email to usr1" usr1@localhost
```

If the hudson job got executed, then your /etc/aliases setup works.

I suspect your problem could be your Linux box cannot receive emails. See if this works first before you setup the redirection in /etc/aliases. To check for incoming emails, login as usr1 and run mail at the shell prompt.